# SELinux always set to permissive, how to set enforcing permanently?

Tags: security, boot, kernel, selinux

I flash a custom ROM to my HTC B2UL.
The ROM, by default, has the SELinux policy set to Permissive instead of Enforcing.

I can use `adb shell setenforce 1` to make SElinux enforcing. But after reboot, SElinux status still return to Permissive.

**Is there any way to make SElinux always be Enforcing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526) and [this issue](https://github.com/jcadduono/android_external_dirtycow/issues/2#issuecomment-354467538) for details on how SELinux is enforced on Android. In short it depends on cmdline parameters of `kernel` and build configuration of `init`.

Check on your device:

```
~# cat /proc/cmdline
```

It must contain `androidboot.selinux=permissive`. You need to remove this parameter from kernel cmdline permanently in order to enforce SELinux on boot. This can be done by unpacking `boot.img`, modifying, repacking and re-flashing. Use [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) or [magiskboot](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/tools.html#magiskboot). Or you can also try [Kernel Selinux Patcher](https://github.com/Zackptg5/Kernel-Sepolicy-Patcher).

But make sure you have a working `sepolicy` on your device or you may get into bootloop. Custom ROMs are usually `userdebug` builds with incomplete policy.