# How to boot system-as-root device always as rooted?

Tags: samsung, root-access, rom-flashing, aosp, systemless-root

I have a Samsung S10 5G device that is actually a `system-as-root` device. I have rooted it by following the instructions given [here](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root).

As the `system-as-root` devices have no `ramdisk` in `boot.img` but in `recovery.img` so, I have to always boot the device with a recovery combination to get the root access.

Is there any way to achieve the root on a normal reboot?

I have a full ROM image of the device so, I believe there should be some way. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-patch-system-img-to-root-the-samsung-s10-5g-qualcomm-device.4005919/post-81742693

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go through [**How Magisk works**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) and [**How to manually root a phone**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526) it would be easy for you to figure out why it's impossible to achieve what you are looking for.

`init` is the very first process started by kernel, which at its early stage sets SELinux `enforcing` (if it's not [already `enforcing`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526)). Before that happens, we need to modify SELinux policy so that it doesn't restrict the root daemon (`magiskd`) from running. Also `init.rc` needs to be patched to inject `magiskd` service.

A simple option is to patch `/sepolicy` and modify `/init.rc` when rooting the device and save the files on device. But on `system-as-root` devices both files are on `system.img` (and possibly `vendor.img`), not on `boot.img`. So modifying them would break "**systemless**" approach and other related things, in particular `dm-verity` and OTAs.

Another option is to run a process even before `init` which patches SELinux policy and changes `init.rc` on the go. And the easy way to achieve this is to replace original `init` file with Magisk `init` so that kernel executes the latter. However on SAR devices `init` is also on `system.img`, so we can't replace it. But we can always boot to recovery mode which does have a `ramdisk` where Magisk's `init` can be placed and executed before any other process. On `A/B` SAR devices recovery `ramdisk` is in `boot.img`, so Magisk always boots to recovery by forcing kernel to ignore `skip_initramfs` cmdline parameter received from bootloader.

> Is there any way to achieve the root on a normal reboot?

On **non-A/B SAR devices (like yours)** there is no `ramdisk` in `boot.img`, so the only option to retain systemless approach is to place Magisk `init` in recovery `ramdisk` on `recovery` partition, and **always boot to recovery mode**. From there `system.img` is mounted at `/system_root` by Magisk `init`, contents of `ramdisk` are then copied to `/` cleaning everything previously existing, files are added / modified in rootfs `/`, `/system_root/system` is bind-mounted to `/system`, and finally `[/system]/init` is executed for normal boot.

However things have changed with Android 10, now `system.img` is mounted at `/` but the files to be added / modified like `/init.rc` and `/sbin` are overlaid with bind mounts as [tweeted](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1143799584801447937) by Magisk developer.

Comment: You have mentioned "So modifying them would break "systemless" approach and other related things, in particular dm-verity and OTAs." so, Is it possible to root the device with the system-modify approach, disabling dm-verity and not updating the device with OTA updates?

Comment: @VatishSharma yes definitely possible but manually, no automated way.

Comment: Also, Is patching only Magisk policies on `system.img` is enough for service with Magisk context to work?

Comment: Not enough. Do `allow magisk * * *` and `allow * magisk * *`.

Comment: Stuck here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218371/stuck-in-boot-loop-when-unpack-and-pack-system-img