# How to patch `system.img` using MagiskManager patch feature to root the device?

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, linux, selinux, systemless-root

I have a **treble** and **system-as-root** but it is not an **A/B** device. I have rooted it with the help of the MagiskManager patch feature. My understanding is: MagiskManager has modified the following three files for rooting:

1. `boot.img` to remove the signatures.
2. `vbmeta.img` to remove the AVB checks(to stop flashing unauthorized binaries).
3. `recovery.img` to actually root the device by patching `init` and adding some files like `.backup/.magisk`, `.backup/.init`(original init) etc..

Magisk has patched the `recovery.img` to boot the device into root mode if you release the recovery mode key combination at a splash screen.

But my requirement is to always boot as root without needing any key combinations.

I know Magisk needs to patch the SE-Policies and `init` file before the init process is actually started(as it will turn ON the `enforcing` mode). From **treble** device, my understanding is that the `system` partition is mounted before running the `init` script.

I think Magisk developers have patched the `recover.img` because they want to follow the `systemless-root` approach and support for the OTA updates.

So, I want to know if MagiskManager is capable of patching my `system.img` file to root the device?

I know the root will be lost if any OTA will come or maybe my device will fail to update the system but this is ok with me as long as I can root it again with the same method :)

This is also fine if instead of rooting on `system.img`, I will be able to patch the `zImage` to always boot in recovery as root mode.

Please suggest if it is feasible or not. If yes then how?

Comment: It doesn't need to modify the system image – that's the idea behind it. Magisk uses "overlay file systems" to achieve that goal. And it comes with its own SuperUser, which you can configure from inside MagiskManager.

Comment: I understand that Magisk doesn't need to modify the `system.img` and is not recommended but my requirement is different: I can not go with recovery boot and don't need OTA updates. I just need a device that always reboots as root.

Comment: That's what Magisk already does. No change needed.

Comment: @Izzy you need to press key combo for recovery mode to boot with magisk root for some newer devices

Comment: @VatishSharma interesting question, maybe you can request this as feature in magisk support. how about other (older) classic root methods with SuperSU or KingRoot they can be installed in /system

Comment: Just a stupid idea, what happens if you swap boot and recovery partitions (flash patched recovery.img to boot)? Shouldn't it then boot into magisk by default?

Comment: @alecxs interesting. On non-A/B SAR devices `boot.img` doesn't have a ramdisk, kernel mounts `system.img` as rootfs `/` and then executes `/init`. Recovery kernel executes `/init` from recovery ramdisk. So both partitions have different headers and bootloader passes different command-lines to both kernels. If `recovery.img` is flashed to `boot` partition, I think bootloader won't extract recovery ramdisk since key combination isn't applied. But it depends on bootloader implementation, may work on some devices.

Comment: related/background https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218222

Comment: @alecxs yeah I answered that. Actually it's possible to patch `system.img` for permanent root in normal boot without booting to recovery. But that requires some hassle (unnecessary in my opinion).

Comment: ... it was easier the days before selinux, just pushing /system/bin/su and /system/app/supersu.apk and chmod 6755 or something

Comment: how about 'reboot recovery' as init.d script (kinda stupid hack)?

Comment: feel inspired by the "bootless root" method (suboot script) maybe this will give you idea https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/amazing-temp-root-mediatek-armv8-t3922213/post79626434

Comment: @alecxs Apps can't reboot device, so `reboot recovery` needs to be done from `adb` (which isn't a less hassle than keeping keys pressed on reboot). Or `init.rc` (and hence `system.img`) needs to be modified to run some reboot script. If `system.img` is to be modified then it's better to run `magiskd` from there, rather rebooting to recovery. // `su` with `6755` (even with `permissive` SELinux) doesn't work because zygote starts apps with PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS and PR_CAPBSET_DROP. `set-uid` is of no use.

Comment: Stuck here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218371/stuck-in-boot-loop-when-unpack-and-pack-system-img

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s10/samsung-galaxy-s10--s10--s10-5g-cross-device-development-exynos/g97xf-multi-disabler-encryption-t3919714

Comment: I am out of my work place; will try it later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: seems it is a classic chicken-and-egg situation. the cat bites its own tail