# Stuck in boot loop after "Fixing SELinus contexts"

Tags: boot-loop, selinux

So, let's say that I have already "Fixed SELinux Contexts", and I am now in a boot loop. How could I resolve this issue.

I am quite new to all of this, but I am eager to learn and fix my mistake.

TWRP-3.3.1-1210
Redmi Note 8 Pro
Havoc-OS-v2.9-20190914-phhgsi_arm64_ab

Comment: May help understand what you have done: [What does TWRP “Fix Contexts” do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218409/218526)