# Can't write to internal storage on a rooted phone

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, permissions, internal-sd, file-permissions

I have a Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016) which I rooted with Magisk.

Now in the process of installing TWRP and customizing my phone, I might have run some shell commands, like `mount` or `sudo` in a place where I shouldn't had.

So now some folders in my `/sdcard/` are now "locked". Apps can't write to them like Whatsapp, Telegram, Camera, for example the messaging apps can't download any media, I can't take any picture with Camera.

When I try to delete a folder or a file with the built-in File Manager, it just doesn't succeed.

With `adb shell` I tried this command: `rm -r /sdcard/Telegram/Telegram Images` but I get permission denied, but running it as root works: `su -c rm -r /sdcard/Telegram/Telegram Images`.

What I did was, I checked ownership and read/write accesses with `ls -al` and I compared the results with a normal phone, EVERYTHING looks fine! User owner is `root` and group owner is `sdcard_rw`, folder permissions look like this `drwxrwx--x` and file permissions look like this: `-rw-rw----`.

This issue has been hunting me for a couple of months, my phone is almost unusable, sometimes app work, sometimes they don't. Please tell me how I can provide more information to help solve this problem, thanks very much.

Comment: [sdcard Fix Permissions script](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=4459553&d=1522203619)

Comment: In most cases `restorecon -R /data/media` should fix this. Details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218409/218526

Comment: btw *'rm -r /sdcard/Telegram/Telegram Images'* actually will remove two files/directories namely *"/sdcard/Telegram/Telegram"* and also *"./Images"* (from your current pwd). you must quote paths containing whitespaces *"/sdcard/Telegram/Telegram Images"*