# SELinux permissive kernel - is it a security risk?

Tags: security, kernel, selinux, oneplus-7

As in title. I am talking of Kernel, not ROM (plenty of questions dealing with ROM on this site).

I have a OnePlus 7 running stock Android 10 and prefer a custom kernel. Of late, OnePlus hasn't released source for kernel and this has played havoc with all custom kernels in OnePlus 7 and other variants. So, I want to flash a [kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=81300967&postcount=605) 
that is independent of the changes One Plus makes.

Only problem is that it is **SELinux permissive** and therefore I want to understand the security risks before flashing it.

Edit:
As requested in comments (deleted) :

```
-# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM is not set
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE is not set
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_AVC_STATS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE=0
- # zcat  /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_SELINUX
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
-# mount | grep selinuxfs
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102657/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-irfan-latif).

Comment: With the permissive kernel flashed the output is identical to the one in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELinux is a security framework which restricts (kernel and userspace) processes within their domains according to defined policy. So the ultimate goal is to load a working policy, label filesystems with proper contexts and set SELinux `enforcing`. It doesn't matter who does this; kernel or some userspace process, though the sooner the better. And `permissive` is an SELinux mode always ready to be switched to `enforcing` mode. However switching other way may or may not be allowed by the policy.

In other words, kernel being SELinux permissive by itself is not a risk, if the the ROM overrides that to make it Enforcing. What SELinux permissive kernel gives you is a flexibility to flash ROMs that demand SELinux permissive or for any other app that needs it. But it is **always advisable to keep the device in SELinux Enforcing state** (`getenforce` on Terminal Emulator will reveal).

Mostly ROM developers build kernel with `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y`. From [kernel configuration](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.14/security/selinux/Kconfig#61):

> With this option enabled, the kernel will start in `permissive` mode (log everything, deny nothing) unless you specify `enforcing=1` on the kernel command line.  You can interactively toggle the kernel between enforcing mode and permissive mode (if permitted by the policy) via `/selinux/enforce`.

Some vendors may disable the said configuration or may add `enforcing=1` boot parameter to kernel cmdline when building `boot.img`, so that SELinux is always enforcing even before the very first userspace process `init` is started. Going a step further ahead Samsung kernel sources are [patched](https://github.com/jcadduono/android_kernel_samsung_exynos7870/commit/c48bd37ff23d4a6a67dff95fc5fb7cf3eb47d521) with options `SECURITY_SELINUX_ENFORCING` and `ALWAYS_ENFORCE`. Other extreme is that SELinux is disabled at all by building with `SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE=y` and writing to `/sys/fs/selinux/disable`, or by building with `SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y` and passing `selinux=0` kernel parameter.

Starting kernel in permissive mode gives the ROM developer and end users freedom to set SELinux mode `permissive` or `enforcing` on boot (or even during running OS by writing to `/sys/fs/selinux/enforce`), and develop a policy according to the requirements. That's how `userdebug`/`eng` builds of ROMs are debugged. `init` can be forced to set SELinux `permissive` on boot by setting `androidboot.selinux=permissive` boot parameter.

OEMs switch to `user` builds when releasing stock ROMs once `sepolicy` is fully developed. `init` on `user` builds [always sets SELinux `enforcing`](https://github.com/Zackptg5/Kernel-Sepolicy-Patcher/issues/1), so it won't boot with SELinux `disabled`. Custom ROMs, however, usually remain `userdebug` which allow root access ([`adb root`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526) and [`/system/xbib/su`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526)) and other relaxations. Some more details can be found in [What sepolicy context will allow any other context to access it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526)

So while `disabled` or `permissive` SELinux in kernel or ROM makes the device equally vulnerable, a `permissive` kernel is usually a good thing (at least for ROM developers and power users). Enforcing kernel is an overkill unless the user is glued to the stock ROM throughout life of a device. However if SELinux is `disabled` (e.g. built without `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y`), stock ROM will [get into bootloop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/init/selinux.cpp#395).

- If kernel is built with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG`, [`extract-ikconfig`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.14/scripts/extract-ikconfig) shell script can be used to check build configuration without flashing to device. On running OS `zcat /proc/config.gz` can be used.
- ROM build type can be checked with `getprop ro.build.type`.
- Kernel commandline boot parameters can be checked by extracting `boot.img`. On running OS `cat /proc/cmdline` can be used.

Comment: As always, a very thorough answer from you. Much appreciated :)

Comment: For readers - I flashed the kernel in question and happily so after the thorough explanation by Irfan

Comment: @beeshyams thanks :)

Comment: Great explanation!  I couldn't figure out how to build a kernel with SELinux permissive until this post.