# How to force SELinux to permissive even when setenforce 0 is not working and kernel was 100% permissive when flashed?

Tags: kernel, selinux, resurrection-remix-os

I don't know what to do, I'm using Samsung Note 3 (Exynos) - N900 with custom Resurrection Remix 5.8.5 ROM (Android 7.1.2) with it's own permissive kernel and rooted with Magisk. Yesterday it turned to enforcing status, then SPenCommand stopped working. And when I tried to setenforce 0 in terminal, it gave me error: invalid argument. I don't want to flash phone again, backup takes a lot of time, as well as restoring, because I have very old PC and I flashed it on friend's laptop who is now 50 miles away and won't come just because of this (my computer still uses USB 1.1 interface - I know it's garbage but its working for 15 years stable. Any suggestions how to do it on phone itself, would be helpful. Please help me somebody :)

Comment: You can try this app https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2524485

Comment: My answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219884/218526) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209374/218526) explain why `setenforce 0` may not work. The only reason I know is the extra security Samsung (and some other OEMs) uses in their kernel configuration. Check your kernel configuration to make sure.