# SELiunix Change in Knox enabled phone

Tags: samsung-knox

Hello every one I have problem to change my Phone SE from "Enforcing" mode to "Permisive" to use my USB Joystick on my phone, my phone is A72018(Rooted) but with Knox security. I used an app called "SELunix changer" it apears Permisive mode enabled but when I use USB/BT Joystick its says it is still on enforcing mode

Is there any app recomnded to change to Permisive mode or any recomnded app to use USB joystick with Enforcing mode?

Thank You

Comment: [You will need to flash a Kernel that supports SELinux permissive](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219884/131553)

Comment: if your device is rooted with Magisk in addition to the enforcing samsung kernel please note permissive mode is deprecated. instead magisk module developers must add custom sepolicy rules